# How do I use a user's input as 1 of the arguments for an sql function?

Tags: php, sql

*This is a simplified version of the code

I have a query

```
SELECT func('123', x, '789');
```

where X is dependent on the user's input into a text box;

I tried

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT func('123', _GET['x'], '789')");
```

where x is retrieved from

```
<form method="get">
    x: <input type="text" name="x"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

however, this doesn't seem to work. Also, does the position of the PHP within the html make a difference?

Here is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$string_connection = "host=localhost port=5432 user=myname dbname=mydb";
$conn = pg_connect($string_connection);

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', $_GET['x'], '789')");

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "$row[0]";
    echo "<br/>\n";
}

?>

<form method="get">
    End Date: <input type="text" name="x"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is `$_GET` not `_GET`

Comment: Plus, `name"x"` missing `=` change to `name="x"`

Comment: it should be $_GET['x']

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran ok, I added the $, but now the page won't load the html

Comment: You need to show us more code then @Senju How is your HTML being populated?

Comment: Also,using `$_GET` directly isn't the safest and is open to attacks.Always use prepared parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

Use:

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
```

then use `($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', '$x', '789')")`

```
$string_connection = "host=localhost port=5432 user=myname dbname=mydb";
$conn = pg_connect($string_connection);

$x = $_GET['x'];

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', '$x', '789')");

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "$row[0]";
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

and if it's an `int`, use `$x = (int)$_GET['x'];`

---

#### Original answer

`name"x"` missing `=` change to `name="x"`

also, either use `$_GET['x']` or `{$_GET['x']}`

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT func('123',{$_GET['x']}, '789')");
```

and

```
<form method="get">
    x: <input type="text" name="x"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: After adding the $ to _GET the page will not even load the form. before the $ it would load the form, but the form would not work

Comment: Ok, then use `_GET` as you had it, but the `=` sign was missing from your `name"x"` @Senju that's the most likely case.

Comment: Hold on, going to upload the entire code, just getting it on this computer first

Comment: @Fred-ii- There was an error in your code,it should be `{$_GET['x']}` .

Comment: Thanks @phpcoderx I will change it back to what it was before. I will give the OP a few options.

Comment: Nobody using prepared statements with data from superglobals any more? :O

Comment: ok, so it's now {$_GET['x']} and the page loads correctly, but it does not print out the answer after submitting

Comment: @Senju Reload my answer, I came up with a slightly different method.

Comment: @Senju You may need to remove the quotes in `echo "$row[0]";` to `echo $row[0];`

Comment: @techouse I'm just trying to get the OP out of a bind (no pun intended) ;-)

Comment: @Senju Curious, aren't you supposed to select a table? I.e.: `SELECT column FROM table` or is `get_champ` your table? I'm confused as to how it's used and if you're selecting a table at all.

Comment: It works with the quotes around $row[0] if I type in the argument directly in the function instead of trying to get it from input, so I don't think that's the problem. Does it matter if the datatype is DATE for the function if the user is inputting the text in the YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: No, I select the table in the function. It works if I tell it pq_query($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', '2012-01-01', '789')"); just not when I have {$_GET['x']}

Comment: It could matter. @Senju I just don't know what will happen if you change your column type; it could have severe consequences. I've seen it happen before where someone changed the column type and lost all data.

Comment: Did you try `$x = $_GET['x'];` then use `($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', '$x', '789')")` @Senju or `($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', $x, '789')")` and `x` is a DATE type you said?

Comment: Try `($conn, "SELECT get_champ('123', '".$_GET['x']."', '789')")` @Senju

Comment: I just tried $x = $_GET['x']; It did not work with $x, but it does with '$x'. Thanks! What a mission.

Comment: Yea, problem solved. Would upvote if I had the 15 rep =/

Comment: "What a mission"... indeed! Am glad it was solved :-) No worries about the upvote, cheers @Senju